# susy: reverse flow direction mid-row

Tags: sass, susy-sass

I'm building an asymmetrical grid layout with Susy 2.0.0 where grid items sometimes need to float left or right to allow a running text to continue uninterrupted.

For example, I may want to align a video to the left, right, or center of a paragraph in my running text. You know, like floats usually behave. Except that here, the constraints of my project force me to have *each paragraph as the sole item on a row* if there are no other items to be displayed as asides.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vbuflsjun1p4shm/Screenshot%202014-04-12%2017.31.06.png

In this specific case:

1. The video on the right must line up next to the right edge of the running text.
2. The running text must continue unbroken without clearing the video

I've tried using the Last Flow setting but this doesn't seem to help much at all. In fact, when I use that along with `@include post(1)`, the generated post margin isn't even equal to the width of the last column – it looks more like the width of the left-most column instead.

Let me know if anything needs clarification, or if it would help for me to throw it in Codepen or someplace like that.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="sup">
  <figure class="sup-content">
    <div class="video"></div>
    <figcaption class="sup-content-caption"></figcaption>
  </figure>
  <div class="sup-grafs">
    <p>A secure is an unstriped bomber. What we don’t know for sure is whether or not the snowless credit comes from a meagre size.</p>
    <p>What we don’t know for sure is whether or not a tuna is a liver’s mexico. A lotion can hardly be considered a tearless rest without also being a save.</p>
    <p>A kookie expansion’s chill comes with it the thought that the podgy chair is a japan. Few can name an unsafe editorial that isn’t a sodden bra. Few can name a tinny bee that isn’t a luckless rhinoceros.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### SCSS

```
$susy-grid-sup: (1 2 1 3 3 1 3 2);

$susy: (
  columns: $susy-grid-sup,
  gutters: 1/4,
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  gutter-position: inside,
  last-flow: to,
  debug: (
    image: show,
  ),
);

p {
  @include pre(3);
  @include span(2 at 4);
  @include break();
}

.sup--right {

  .sup-grafs {
    p {
      @include nobreak();
    }
  }

  .sup-content {
    @include span(2 at 2 last);
    @include post(1);
    @include break();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite right. The problem you are having is related to the `location` argument, not the flow direction. I'll try to answer both.

When you are using asymmetrical grids, you have to be very clear about the `location` (`at`) argument any time you are spanning columns (both `span` and `post` here). Currently, your video is being set to the width of columns 2-3, with a margin-after that is the width of column 1.

Try this:

```
.sup-content {
  @include span(2 at 6 last);
  @include post(last 1);
  @include break();
}
```

Susy will use `last` to determine a location, if an explicit column index is not given.

You can also change the flow direction in your shorthand by adding `rtl` or `ltr` — though I'm not sure it will help you at all in this case because it flips the entire understanding of your grid. We could easily add `right` and `left` float override arguments, and probably should. Feel free to submit an [issue on github](https://github.com/ericam/susysite/issues/).